# line ending with Multiple underscores

Tags: java

Could you please let me know how to check whether the line ending with multiple underscores.

am able to check whether string ends with underscore but not able to get the count of number of underscores at the end of line.

Based on the underscores count i need to assign localNumberOfColumns

```
if(line.endsWith("_")){
    localNumberOfColumns=NumberOfColumns-1;
}else{
    localNumberOfColumns=NumberOfColumns;
}
```

Comment: So are you trying to *check whether the line ending with multiple underscores* or get the *number of underscores at the end of line*?

Comment: you need re,or you can write a while loop

Comment: It is easy to get special character occurrence in a line but I don't know what do you meaning by the end of a line, Do you have any pattern?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What first came to mind for me was simply comparing the length of your input string against the length of your string with all final underscores removed.

```
String threeUS = "abc123___";
int numUS = threeUS.length() - threeUS.replaceAll("(?:_)*$", "").length();
System.out.println("Number of underscores: " + numUS);
```

**Output:**

```
Number of underscores: 3
```

**Demo here:**

## Rextester

Comment: Or you can replace `_+$`.

Answer (score 2):

You can [`split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) of all final underscores, and then compare the length of the original input with the length of the input with the underscores removed:

```
 String s = "abc123___";
 String sWithoutUnderscores = s.split("_*$")[0];
 int numberOfUnderscores = s.length() - sWithoutUnderscores.length();
```

**Update**

As pointed out in the comments, above solution fails for cases where the string contains only underscores. If that is a possibility in your domain, consider using Java's pattern matching utilities:

```
String s = "abc123___";
Matcher matcher = Pattern.compile("_*$").matcher(s);
int numberOfUnderscores = matcher.find() ? matcher.group().length() : 0;
```

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen So? My pattern only splits of the ones at the end of the string (`$`).

Comment: This solution breaks for strings that only have underscores.

Comment: Nice. That's a clean solution.